# image goes over the padding of the container tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a widget sidebar and I am encountering problems with the displayed image. The sidebar has a padding of 20px from all sides and the image's width is set to auto. However, when I display the images, it goes over the padding of the container instead of making its size adjusted to the padding. Here is the code (CSS):

```
aside {
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<aside> 
  <div class="widget">
     <img src="/disk.png">
  </div>
<aside>
```

The widget class has no style, as I haven't implemented it due to this problem. Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/10BPS.jpg (thats where the container ends). How can I fix this issue? How can I make the image's width to be 20px less automatically, so it aligns with the CSS rules of the parent?

Comment: Would be awesome if you'll supply any fiddle

Comment: I found the answer, The problem was the at fixed position as for some reason it was moving it to the right by -20px...

Comment: please autoanswer you question so it doesn't keep open.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. When using fixed CSS position without the right attribute, at least in safari and chrome, the block would align against the parent container's width. So, if the block is:

```
<nav style="position:fixed;left:0px;width:80px;">
</nav>
<main style="margin-left:80px;padding:10px;position:relative">
   <div class="content" style="width:80%">
   </div>
   <aside style="width:20%;position:fixed;top:0px"> 
      <div class="widget">
         <img src="/disk.png">
      </div>
   <aside>
</main>
```

The aside would look like a right sidebar that fits the `main` element. But since the fixed position's width is relative the window, not the parent, its right position would basically start from off the screen, and the "20%" would be 20% to the parent, ignoring the other width. I don't know why safari and chrome render it this way, but because of that and the unluckiness of image size being 10px smaller than the aside element, I couldn't figure out how this problem is even possible.

So, to get what I wanted, I change the `aside`s position to `absolute` and added `overflow-y:scroll` to my `content` class as the right bar should never move. Yes, I could play with width of the right bar but in my project that's the least of my concerns right now